# LINQ selection by type of an object

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I have a collection which contains two type of objects A & B.

```
Class Base{}
Class A : Base {}
Class B : Base {}

List<Base> collection = new List<Base>();
collection.Add(new A());
collection.Add(new B());
collection.Add(new A());
collection.Add(new A());
collection.Add(new B());
```

Now I want to select the objects from the collection based on its type (A or B, not both).

How I can write a LINQ query for this? Otherwise I need to loop through the collection, which I don't want to.

Edit:

Thank you all for your help. Now I can use OfType() from LINQ. But I think in my case it won't work. My situation is

```
Class Container
{
  List<Base> bases;
}

List<Container> containers = new List<Container>();
```

Now I want to select the container from containers, which has at least one type A. Maybe this can't be done by LINQ.

Comment: Could you expand on your edit? What do you mean by "select the container"?

Comment: I don't get this either.

Comment: `containers.SelectMany(c => c.Bases).OfType<A>()`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can use the [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) Linq method for that:

```
var ofTypeA = collection.OfType<A>();
```

Regarding your unwillingness to loop throught the collection, you should keep in mind that Linq does not do magic tricks; I didn't check the implementation of `OfType`, but I would be surprised *not* to find a loop or iterator in there.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. I have one more question, if more than one person answered correctly, which answer I need to make as "Correct answer"?

Comment: @Jai: You should mark the answer that you found most useful or helpful. Both Jared and Fredrik are correct, but Fredrik's answer had more depth and may help you learn more.

Comment: @Jai: flip a coin? There is a coin-flipper here, if you need one: http://www.random.org/coins/?num=1&cur=20-novelty.voting-2004 - couldn't find a voting coin between me and @JaredPar, so you'll have to do with Kerry vs. Bush. I'll leave it to you to decide who is who ;)

Comment: ~13yr later I come along to say, that while yes, linq and similar tech does looping internally at some level, there's usually benefit to using it when doing so makes the code shorter and more concise.  (Granted some notation is more obfuscating than clarity providing.)    Secondly,  one hopes that the language designer's implementation is both efficient and well tested.    (Test for both to the degree that it matters to your code).

Answer (score 15):

For completeness, here is the source code of `Enumerable.OfType<T>`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> OfType<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
    return OfTypeIterator<TResult>(source); 
}

static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source) {
    foreach (object obj in source) {
        if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
    } 
}
```

You can see that it lazily evaluates the source stream.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the OfType extension method for this

```
IEnumerable<A> filteredToA = list.OfType<A>();
IEnumerable<B> filteredToB = list.OfType<B>();
```