# Using LINQ to get objects of type from a list

Tags: c#

Please see the code below:

```
public interface IVehicle {
}

public class Car : IVehicle {
}

public class Lorry : IVehicle {
}
```

and the client code below:

```
var Vehicles = new List<IVehicle>();
Vehicles.Add(new Car());
Vehicles.Add(new Lorry());
var Vehicles2 = new List<IVehicle>();
Vehicles2.Add(Vehicles.OfType<Car>() as IVehicle);
```

A null value is added to the list after the last line is run.  How can I ensure that the Car is added to the list.

I got my idea from here: [LINQ selection by type of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842714/linq-selection-by-type-of-an-object).

Comment: You mean like `Vehicles2.Add(Vehicles.OfType<Car>().First())`? Though this would throw an exception when there is no `Car` in the list...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be a lot of `Car` items within your `List<IVehicle>` so you have to use `AddRange`

```
Vehicles2.AddRange(Vehicles.OfType<Car>());
```

approach with Linq `Where`

```
Vehicles2.AddRange(Vehicles.Where(x =>  x.GetType() == typeof(Car)));
```

---

> @fubo, it is guaranteed that there will only every be one

If there is always one and you just want to add that one with `Add` you can also use `Single()` to select that `Car` - note: `Single()` throws an Exception if there isn't exactly one item.

```
Vehicles2.Add(Vehicles.OfType<Car>().Single());
```

Comment: there will always be one Car in the list in this case.  Can you amend your answer to cater for this?

Comment: @w0051977 What is there to amend?

Comment: @Servy, just wanted to make the code more readable, so someone doesn't look at it in six months and think; "why addrange there is only one?"

Comment: @fubo, it is guaranteed that there will only every be one.

Comment: @w0051977 Then feel free to write the code differently in your production application, if your problem is actually different than the question you asked.

Comment: +1 for the edit.  Please leave Add and AddRange in your answer as it may help me (or others) in future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would note that the actual problem is that you're casting `IEnumerable<Car>` to `IVehicle`. The cast apparently fails and `as` operator returns `null`.

So the solution here, as others have already pointed, is to either obtain a single `IVehicle` object (e.g. via `.Single` or `.First`), or to add the whole sequence to the list via `.AddRange`.